# Unit test controller logic in ASP.NET Core that returns IEnumerable<someobject> in JsonResult

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have a unit test to verify the controller method `GetUser`, and I want to investigate the `resultsets` for any errors.

```
public void TestApiGetUser()
{
    GenericController controller = new GenericController();
    var result = controller.GetUser();
    result.ShouldNotBeNull();
    var resultObject = Assert.IsType<JsonResult>(result);
    var data = ((ActionResult<IEnumerable<Resultset>>)(JsonResult)result).Value as IEnumerable<Resultset>; //this is returning null
    //how to access data.Any(x => x.IsError) to test if there is any error in the API call?
}
```

The controller has the following `GetUser` endpoint like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("User")]
public JsonResult GetUser()
{       
    var result = _apiOrchestrator.GetUserData();
    return Json(result);
}
```

and the `GetUserData()` looks like:

```
public IEnumerable<Resultset> GetUserData()
{
    IEnumerable<Resultset> result = null;
    //Some code
    //Fill result object with user data
    return result;
}
```

The `Resultset` object looks like this:

```
public class Resultset
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public bool IsError { get; set; } = false;
    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }
}
```

I have read many articles here in SO but didn't see anything working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

`UPDATE 2`:
If I do this:

```
var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<Resultset>(resultObject.Value);
Assert.True(resultsets.Any(x=>x.IsError));
```

I think I got somewhere with above code. But, is this is best method?

Comment: You're creating an instance of `GenericController` with default constructor (no params).  Inside `GetUser`, you have this code: `var result = _apiOrchestrator.GetUserData();`. Question: What is the value of `_apiOrchestrator` when debugging your test?

Comment: That is initiated in the constructor and is a valid object. And, GenericController does return the data back to the unit test.

Comment: I updated my post with a solution I think worked, but need a suggestion, if that is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple than I thought. Here is the solution if someone is looking for this specific use-case where they are trying to evaluate an `IEnumerable<T>`. I am sure there are other ways too, but this is what made my test work. Feel free to add your solution for future reference.

```
public void TestApiGetUser()
{
    GenericController controller = new GenericController();
    var result = controller.GetUser();
    var resultsets = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<Resultset>>(result.Value);
    Assert.DoesNotContain(resultsets, x => x.IsError);
    Assert.DoesNotContain(resultsets, x => x.ErrorMessages.Count > 0);
}
```